# What implementation of Swap() function is better and for what situations?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, std, swap

I have defined two functions:

1).

```
template<class T> inline
void swap(T &first, T &second)
{   
    if (&first != &second)
    {
        T tmp = first;
        first = second;
        second = tmp;
    }
}
```

2).

```
template<typename T>
inline void SwapMe(T *first, T *second)
{
    if(*first != *second)
    {
        T tmp = *first;
        *first = *second;
        *second = tmp;
    }
}
```

Which implementation is better (first one equals to the std::swap() ) ?

Comment: Those have somewhat different semantics.

Comment: And different requirements.  The second one requires `operator!=(T,T)`, or something compatible.

Comment: Since this is C++, you should just be using `std::swap<t>`, especially because in C++11 it will use move semantics.

Comment: You might have meant `if (first != second)` in `SwapMe`. Or if not then you might have meant `if (first != second)` in `swap`. Currently `swap` compares addresses whereas `SwapMe` compares the values of the objects pointed to. This difference is unrelated to whether the function takes reference or pointer parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The first version is better with variables passed by reference or passed by value.

The second is better for pointers to values.

They are different because references are a different animal than pointers.

Comment: as for memory management... As I remember, for the pointer memory allocates buffer of 4 bytes ( where the pointer exactly locates ), as for references there is no additional memory allocation. Also the 2nd one is more for pure C, except templates.

Comment: @OlegOrlov: As for memory management, you are still only allocating a type `T` on the stack; so memory management is not an issue here, for both examples.

Comment: T - is only a hint for compiler to paste needed type. It's not a generic type like in C#. So it's not just T, but T* and any pointer equals to void* ( 4 bytes ) and if you explicitly use it memory will allocate some size for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is better, except the first one, because I prefer it.  Other people will prefer the second one, because they think it should be made explicit at the caller's end that a function might modify its arguments.  I'm of the mind that you shouldn't be calling functions if you don't know what they do, and what they do should be obvious by their name, as is the case with swap.  I am also of the mind that the only purpose of raw pointers in C++ is as non-owning, re-seatable and-or nullifiable references.  Except in cases where you are, of necessity, implementing your own memory managing classes, like those in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody says that case 2 is danger. Do you receive a program crash if your code will contains NULL pointer: SwapMe (NULL, NULL)

Comment: you will catch only: error C2974: 'SwapMe' : invalid template argument for 'T', type expected. if you use SwapMe<NULL>(NULL, NULL); or error C2784: 'void SwapMe(T *,T *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from 'int' if you use SwapMe(NULL, NULL) if to use MSC++

Comment: I mean that this code is problemmed if real pointer is null

Comment: it won't even compile with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard function template that does *approximately* the same as your `swap` (namely `std::swap`), and there is a standard function template that does *approximately* the same as your `SwapMe` (namely `std::iter_swap`).

Neither is really "better", they each have their uses. Either of them could be implemented using the other, but as it happens in the standard `iter_swap` is defined in terms of `swap`, so `swap` is thought of as the more fundamental operation. It is `swap` that you would ADL-overload for your own types.

In your code, the `*first != *second` test in your `SwapMe` is highly suspect. It requires `T` to have `operator!=`, and it's not much of an optimization given that `!=` might be quite slow for some types, so it adds a significant cost to the common case (when the objects aren't equal). Furthermore, depending on the definition of the type `T` it may be that swapping equal objects ought to have an effect (in the case of `vector`, for example, the capacity doesn't participate in equality comparisons but it *is* exchanged when you swap using `std::swap` or `vector::swap`). So at the moment `SwapMe` is worse, but I suspect that's not intended :-)

In fact, any such test in a `swap` function is suspect, since it will tend to slow down the common case even if only minutely. But if you make the tests the same then whether they should be there at all is a separate argument from what the parameter types should be.